# Is IPv6 send-to-self possible in linux

Tags: linux, performance-testing, ipv6, sysctl

I am trying to create a setup for testing network equipment, and would like to use multiple (3) NICs in a single PC to produce traffic through an external device, i.e. a network switch. From one interface to another.

All of the tests are for IPv6 and ethernet. All NICs have link local and global IPv6 addresses with the same network/subnet prefix. 
Atm. all packets are routed internally and never use the physical wire.

I see a lot of threads solving the problem for IPv4 using the net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_local parameter together with some routing table fixes. But I can't find a solution for IPv6.

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: You can create multiple network namespaces and put each interface in a separate namespace.

Comment: So far I have only tried to remove entries in the local routing table, and adding unicast routes. But that did not work.

Comment: I will read up on network namespaces and give that a try.